# I'm getting the error in ./src/main.ts file Module not found: Can't resolve types while compiling Angular app with `ng serve`

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module

I have this `main.ts` file:

```
import { enableProdMode, NgModuleRef, Type, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BootstrapPsm } from 'projects/shared/src/lib/service/bootstrap-psm';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import './polyfills';
import './assets/js/libs/pixi.min.js';
import 'foo-dts';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

(Error as any).stackTraceLimit = 100;

const ngZone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: true });

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone })
  .then((ref: NgModuleRef<AppModule>) => {
    const bootstrap: BootstrapPsm = ref.injector.get<BootstrapPsm>(BootstrapPsm as Type<BootstrapPsm>);
    bootstrap.init();
  })
  .catch((err: Error) => console.error(err));
```

And `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "foo-dts": ["./projects/shared/src/lib/types/foo-dts"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

When starting development server through `ng serve` I'm getting this error `ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'foo-dts' in 'C:\Users\someUser\gitProjects\user_interface\projects\baseline\src'`.

The `foo-dts` content is:

```
export {};

declare global {
  const ContentQueue: any;

  interface Date {
    format(value: string): string;
  }

  interface Window {
    __Zone_disable_on_property: any;
    __Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame: any;
    __Zone_disable_XHR: any;
    __Zone_ignore_on_properties: any;
    __zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS: any;
    API: any;
    BUS: any;
    bus: any;
    config: any;
    ContentConfig: any;
    ContentManager: any;
    ContentQueue: any;
    DataRegistry: any;
    global: any;
    hostMessageSender: any;
    LanguageUtils: any;
    lock: any;
    logger: any;
    mdiManager: any;
    METER: any;
    msg: any;
    FooServices: any;
    FooConfig: any;
    RegistryUtils: any;
    serviceMenuController: any;
    XMLHttpRequest: any;
  }
}
```

Theoretically this should import the interfaces, but it doesn't.

When I change the types's code to this:

```
declare module "foo-dts" {
    interface Window {
      ...
    };
}
```

the error disappears, but the properties set to this interface aren't exported globally, because I get errors like: `Property 'FooConfig' does not exist on type 'Window'`.

When I made this file into npm package to get installed during packages installation and it was still exported as `declare global {}` and the imported as `import '@types/foo-dts';`, the `ERROR ... module not found` still was present.

Really can't nail the proper solutions to this.

Comment: If the .js are commons to all the app, the .js should be **only** add in angular.json (not in main.ts)

Comment: how is the file name ? is it ending in `.d.ts`

Comment: `foo-dts` types are inside `index.d.ts` file. @Matthieu Riegler

Comment: Found an answer to [Adding custom types in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63200166/22246271) question.
Looks like I need not to import types in components nor in `main.ts`, just include custom types files inside `typeRoots` array in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Nah, doesn't work.
Types not getting recognized by TS.

Comment: This answer for my other question, [ERROR in src/app/providers.ts:152:36 - error TS2339: Property 'API' does not exist on type 'Window' - error with TypeScript custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008141/22246271) did help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by browsing through various similar topics and tried a bit of everything.

But ultimately I had to package my typings file, so it would be available as another typings module inside `node_modules/@types`, and then add `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],` to root `tsconfig.json` file and the typings package's name into `"types": ["foo-dts"]` arrays inside various `tsconfig.*.json` configs inside subdirectories.

If you have already `"types": ["some_types", "node", "jasmine"]` array inside your config file, you just need add your custom types' name to array in a double quote, like that: `"types": ["some_types", "node", "jasmine", "some_custom_types"]`.

I added them wherever these types are needed.
So if a particular subdirectory doesn't need these types for libraries/components/tests to work, the types aren't there.

The `"types"` array must be inside `"compilerOptions"` object of `tsconfig.*.json` file.

What I did is I created directory `foo-dts` inside of app's root folder, which is `C:\Users\someUser\gitProjects\user_interface`.

Put there two files.

First is `index.d.ts`:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    __Zone_disable_on_property: any;
    __Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame: any;
    __Zone_disable_XHR: any;
    __Zone_ignore_on_properties: any;
    __zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS: any;
    API: any;
    BUS: any;
    bus: any;
    config: any;
    ContentConfig: any;
    ContentManager: any;
    ContentQueue: any;
    DataRegistry: any;
    global: any;
    hostMessageSender: any;
    LanguageUtils: any;
    lock: any;
    logger: any;
    mdiManager: any;
    METER: any;
    msg: any;
    FooServices: any;
    FooConfig: any;
    RegistryUtils: any;
    serviceMenuController: any;
    XMLHttpRequest: any;
  }
}
export {};
```

Second is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@types/foo-dts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Declaration files for legacy Foos",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "Super-duper license"
}
```

Then, I added `"@types/foo-dts": "file:./foo-dts",` inside `"devDependencies": {}` of app's root `package.json` config.

Then I did `npm i` to install dependecies and voila!

Types are recognized by my IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate flawlessly, during serving the local development server with `ng serve` and during running unit tests with `ng test --watch=false`.

It's unfortunate, though, that such easy fix isn't put explicite into documentation, easy to find and understand.

Had to flounder through both Angular and TypeScript documentations, and various similar problems on StackOverflow and blogs, to finally get it and know how to implement the solution.