# ERROR in src/app/providers.ts:152:36 - error TS2339: Property 'API' does not exist on type 'Window' - error with TypeScript custom types

Tags: angular, typescript, types, module, window

Writing an app in Angular 8 and TypeScript 3.4.5.

When running local Angular development server using `ng server`, I get errors preventing the compilation:

```
ERROR in src/app/providers.ts:152:36 - error TS2339: Property 'API' does not exist on type 'Window'.

152   { provide: API, useValue: window.API },
                                       ~~~
src/environments/environment.static.ts:18:8 - error TS2339: Property 'FooServices' does not exist on type 'Window'.

18 parent.FooServices.Component = (): { subscribe: () => void } => {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/zone-flags.ts:1:8 - error TS2339: Property '__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame' does not exist on type 'Window'.

1 window.__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
```

What I figured out, is to create custom global types extenstion for standard browser's `Window` object.

So I made custom global types:

```
declare global {
  interface Date {
    format(value: string): string;
  }

  interface Window {
    __Zone_disable_on_property: any;
    __Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame: any;
    __Zone_disable_XHR: any;
    __Zone_ignore_on_properties: any;
    __zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS: any;
    API: any;
    BUS: any;
    bus: any;
    config: any;
    ContentConfig: any;
    ContentManager: any;
    ContentQueue: any;
    DataRegistry: any;
    global: any;
    hostMessageSender: any;
    LanguageUtils: any;
    lock: any;
    logger: any;
    mdiManager: any;
    METER: any;
    msg: any;
    FooServices: any;
    FooConfig: any;
    RegistryUtils: any;
    serviceMenuController: any;
    XMLHttpRequest: any;
  }
}

export {};
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "projects/shared/src/lib/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

And theoretically this config should work, because the custom types in `user_interface/projects/shared/src/lib/types/global.d.ts` file are included properly in above config.

But my IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate still keep pointing out type errors in some files that use either `parent.FooServices` or `window.FooConfig` and so on objects.

According to this short post [How to declare global types in TypeScript](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-make-types-global#add-the-path-to-types-to-your-tsconfigjson), this solutions should work fine.

I really don't know what I'm missing and where I did miscalculated.

What I've seen through SO is that many people, from time to time, have same problems with custom typings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for that and similar problem, which I described in an answer to my question [I'm getting the error in ./src/main.ts file Module not found: Can't resolve types while compiling Angular app with `ng serve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77018037/22246271).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `include` field to you tsconfig?

```
"include": [
  'projects/shared/src/lib/types/global.d.ts' // the path must be relevant to the config location
]
```

[image]

Comment: Added `"include": ["projects/shared/src/lib/types/global.d.ts", "projects/baseline/src/main.ts"]` to `tsconfig.json`.
Starting development server now works fine.

But `ng test --watch=false` show similar errors like `ERROR in ../mocks/src/lib/bus-mock.ts:5:13 - error TS2339: Property 'BUS' does not exist on type 'Window'.`, because same types that weren't seen during development server compilation, aren't seen by TypeScript for Karma+Jasmine testing files.
Adding `"../shared/src/lib/types/global.d.ts"` to `include` array in `tsconfig.spec.json` didnt' worked.

Comment: And does the `ng-test` use the same tsconfig? E. g cypress has an option to specify the config to use …

Comment: No, it uses `projects/mocks/tsconfig.spec.json`, where I included the types, but the error remains. Was: `"include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]` and now is: `"include": ["../shared/src/lib/types/global.d.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]`.
Yet, the errors like `ERROR in ../mocks/src/lib/bus-mock.ts:5:13 - error TS2339: Property 'BUS' does not exist on type 'Window'.` remain.